# Quasar - Cordova Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-18.04, quasar-framework

I'm using Ubuntu, am trying to build Quasar project *mode* Cordova target Android.

in my **.bashrc** file:

```
# ANDROID HOME
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools; PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# JAVA HOME PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

when I perform :

> quasar dev -m cordova -T android

after some time I get this response:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /home/user/Android/Sdk
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.8
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

I have tried reinstalling & uninstalling my java versions & I still get this error.

anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by installing java 8

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

then I updated the JAVA_HOME in my .bashrc

```
# JAVA HOME PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

then using java compiler alternatives.

I updated **javac -version** to **javac 1.8.0_265**

with command:
`update-alternatives --config javac`

output:

```
  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode
```

I then selected "2".

I get:

```
// javac -version
javac 1.8.0_265

// java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
```